# Why do i get the error error: expected expression before ‘char’?

Tags: multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

This is my function that prints an array of 10 by 10 '.'

```
void drawMap(char map[10][10]){
    int i, j;
    printf("Now drawing map\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            map[i][j] = '.';
            printf("%c ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The function that uses the above function. I get one error here.

```
void findThecookie(){
    drawMap(char map[10][10], int i, int j);
}
```

This is my main function.

```
int main()     
{

    int gamenumber;
    int randomNumber;
    int guessednum;

    printf("Hello and welcome to my babysitting game.\n");
    printf("Please select your option. Your choices are:\n");
    printf("1) Number guessing game\n" "2) Rock-Paper-Scissors\n" "3) Area of a Random Rectangle\n" "4) Find the Cookie\n" "5) Quit\n");
    scanf("%d", &gamenumber);  
    if(gamenumber == 1){
        numberGuessing();
    }
    if(gamenumber == 2){
        rockPaperscissors();
    }
    if(gamenumber == 3){
        randomRectangle();
    }
```

Another error here

```
if(gamenumber == 4){
    findThecookie(char map[10][10], int i, int j);
}
if(gamenumber == 5){
    printf("Exiting the program\n");
} 

return 0;
```

Everytime i try to compile i get the errors

```
project2.c: In function ‘findThecookie’:
project2.c:22:9: error: expected expression before ‘char’
project2.c: In function ‘main’:
project2.c:171:17: error: expected expression before ‘char’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. You don't use variable types while calling functions. So Instead of calling a function using findThecookie(char map[10][10], int j, int i). It should be findThecookie(map, j, i).
2. findThecookie does not expect any parameters, but you try to give it three.
3. drawMap does expect one parameter, but you give it three.

Read this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm It is a basic tutorial about using functions in C.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

`drawMap()` takes one parameter as input, but you're supplying 3 parameters.